# Data Extension Default Value Length

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, default-value

[image]appears to be 100 characters, is there a way either through Admin/Setup or Support to increase that?

Comment: Hi, not sure what you are trying to achieve? You can specify the length of a text field through the UI, or (with slightly more degrees of freedom) through API. I am not aware of a "default" setting that you can manipulate. - but that also isn't such a good idea from a DB point of view. I would not treat field lengths as arbitrary and just set a generic default. field lengths should be set specifically, with an idea of the data in mind that you want to store.

Comment: setting the length of the attribute is one thing, but the default value in the DE Properties tab is what I'm talking about.  that seems to be limited to 100 characters, and no matter what length I choose for the attribute, that does not impact how many characters the default value field can be, or so it seems.

Comment: got it. Sorry, I don't know an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add a default value for a field from the UI, then the default value box won't let you put more than **128 characters**.

A workaround for this is to use WSProxy to add a new field to the DE with the pre-defined default value for that field.

For example, in the code below I added a new text field with max length is 500 characters and the default value is a sample text with 165 characters.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var customerKey = "Your DE customer Key";
var fields = [
    {
        "Name": "Your field name",
        "FieldType": "Text",
        "MaxLength": 500,
        "DefaultValue": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eget nisi enim. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    }
];

var result = prox.updateItem('DataExtension', {
    "CustomerKey": customerKey,
    "Fields": fields
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out if I created the DE in Contact Builder, I can set the default value to whatever the length of the attribute is.  Tested at both 254 and 500 and was successful.